# In AWS ECS, how can multiple services be linked to a single DNS name?

Tags: amazon-ecs

In my network configuration, based on AWS ECS (using Fargate), I have a service that acts as a "data broker". These "data broker" services need to be able to communicate with each other, because if any one of them receives data, they pass it along to all the others. But outside the service itself, there should be a single DNS name which will distribute traffic to any random data broker.

I am having trouble trying to translate this concept into AWS ECS, allowing each container running a data broker to contact its peers, yet also make a single DNS name available for all of them.

In Kubernetes, this can be performed using a [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) to expose the individual containers, and then use a normal service to expose the group of containers.

In AWS ECS, I could see two possible options:

- Create an ECS Service for each "data broker", each of which runs a single task. However, no load-balancer exists for the full set of data brokers.
- Create an ECS Service for all "data brokers" together, which runs multiple tasks. However, no load-balancer or network name exists for the individual tasks.

Using AWS CDK (Java), my configuration looks roughly like the following:

```
  public List<String> constructDataBrokerServices(Cluster cluster, int count) {
    List<String> dataBrokerUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      dataBrokerUrls.add("broker-" + Integer.toString(i) + ".local");
      Map<String, String> envVars = new HashMap<>();
      List<String> peerUrls = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
          peerUrls.add("broker-" + Integer.toString(j) + ".local");
        }
      }
      envVars.put("PEER_URLS", String.join(",", peerUrls));

      // Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public.
      NetworkMultipleTargetGroupsFargateService loadBalancedFargateService =
          NetworkMultipleTargetGroupsFargateService.Builder.create(this, "brokerService-" + Integer.toString(i))
          .cluster(cluster)    // Required
          .desiredCount(1)     // Default is 1
          .taskImageOptions(NetworkLoadBalancedTaskImageProps.builder()
              .containerName("broker")
              .image(ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(
                      Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, "broker", "broker"),
                      "latest"))
              .environment(envVars)
              .build())
          .loadBalancers(List.of(
                  NetworkLoadBalancerProps.builder()
                  .name("lb-" + Integer.toString(i))
                  .listeners(List.of(NetworkListenerProps.builder()
                      .name("listener-" + Integer.toString(i))
                      .build()))
                  .publicLoadBalancer(true)
                  .build()))
          .targetGroups(List.of(
                  NetworkTargetProps.builder()
                  .listener("listener-" + Integer.toString(i))
                  .build()))
          .cloudMapOptions(CloudMapOptions.builder()
              .name("broker-" + Integer.toString(i))
              .build())
          .build();
```

Is this even possible with AWS ECS? Should I try to re-write my infrastructure to be based on Kubernetes instead?

Comment: In your second scenario (Create an ECS Service for all "data brokers" together, which runs multiple tasks. However, no load-balancer or network name exists for the individual tasks.) each task would be at a separate path of the load balancer. Is that not good enough? If not, you'll need to add AWS Cloud Map, or AWS App Mesh, or a third party tool like HashiCorp Consul to your configuration.

Comment: In this case, it would not be good enough, because there would be no way to initialize the brokers so that they replicate their data to its peers.

The purpose of the brokers in my case is to split network load, however, the consumers still need access to all the data, no matter which broker it was sent to.

I am currently using CloudMap, however, it seems to only allow 1 name per service (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: OK it sounds like you need to use AWS App Mesh instead (or a third-party service mesh), which is much more advanced and has more features, like load balancing.

Comment: You are probably correct. I'm digging into it now to see what AWS App Mesh can offer.  Thank you kindly for the advice!

Comment: After spending some time configuring AWS App Mesh, I discovered that there are some serious limitations, namely, only a single ELB Listener is supported per Virtual Node (https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-roadmap/issues/120), this means that any service that uses more than 1 port (like mine) cannot be configured this way.

For now, I am simply deploying multiple ECS Services with different names in Cloud Map, e.g. broker-0.local, broker-1.local, etc. and then moving the task of load balancing between them to the calling services.